# Using `git clean` in a folder deleted its contents

Tags: git

I was trying to use Git in a folder then I used `git glean -df` and I found everything gone.

Does that mean I lost my files and is there any way to get them back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you ran `git clean -df` you [asked](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) Git to

> Remove untracked files from the working tree

[including directories](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#git-clean--d). You also [told Git to ignore its safety net](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#git-clean--f).

If Git knows about the files (i.e. if they've ever been `add`ed or `stash`ed, [even if they were never `commit`ed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12434618/354577)) then they should be recoverable. Try running `git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable` and then looking in `.git/lost-found/` for objects that you deleted.

Otherwise there is no way for Git to retrieve them; you'll have to rely on other tools like an existing backup, filesystem snapshots, file synchronization tools, or filesystem recovery tools.

Comment: Hi @E.Aly. how do you recover these  other files by command

Comment: @tktktk0711, I'm not sure what you're asking. Is the answer not clear?